# how to show HTML code in column?

Tags: calculated-column

how can i force sharepoint2007 (MOSS) to interpret HTML code instead of showing it?

I have a column which calculates a yes or no (depending on other columns) within a HTML (i want to show images too). This column is not interpreted by sharepoint. HTML is shown in the column plain.

What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Since SP2010 you can also add JavaScript in Calculated Columns (set to datatype=Number) All *pros* and *cons* at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the solution described in this post:
[Using calculated columns to write HTML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113884/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html)

---

**original post** (links are broken)

elcapitano, my tutorial should work:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

A couple notes:

- in the above post, you'll find a link to a troubleshooting page
- there are several versions of the Text to HTML script, I recommend that you pick the latest one (v 2.1.1) here:
  http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Downloads/

If it doesn't work, feel free to share your HTML string (calculated column output) and I'll take a look.

Comment: after working on the troubleshooting page, it worked! Thanks!!!! Anyway i think i have to develop a system-wide function which allows to display html.

Comment: Please provide a summary for the answer you are linking to.

Comment: The link is broken as of 2017-03-28

Answer (score 14):

By far the easiest method to do this is to simply set the "data type returned from this formula" setting on your column to be "Number".

Against all logic, this interprets your formula as HTML. I'm not sure if this works in 2007, but it certainly works in 2010 and 2013. Since there are 10,000 views on this topic and very few up votes, I'm guessing this is a much better answer for the wider community than any of the answers given.

Comment: Brilliantly simple and so typical of Msft's leaky programming.

Comment: true. thanks for the upvote, really hoping more people use this solution and less people use the others...

Comment: Tremendous - nifty workaround until I can get SP Designer configured

Comment: Since SP2010 you can also add JavaScript in Calculated Columns (set to datatype=Number) All *pros* and *cons* at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: "really hoping more people use this solution" yes, so that if this undocumented 'feature' is patched in SharePoint 2016 or whatever, all those painstakingly built HTML columns will be useless. good idea!

Comment: Trying this out with a calculated column that gives an html link, I found that by setting the "data type returned from this formula" to "Date & Time" you can get the result left-aligned instead of right-aligned as well.

Comment: **You can't do this anymore in SPO** - you can do it on-prem if you have certain extra settings defined.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields

Answer (score 3):

We've recently released a free HTML Calculated Column; it acts just like a calculated column, but won't escape HTML:

[Pentalogic's SharePoint HTML Calculated Column](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/free-stuff/html-calculated-column)

**Disclaimer:** I work for Pentalogic; on this project actually. Oh, and I'm afraid you have to sign up for our newsletter, but that isn't a bad trade (in my unbiased opinion). :)

Comment: This is very nice and works without you knowing much code - just a teensy bit.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone needs help with the calculated column formulae, we also have a cheatsheet on our site.

Comment: Nice work @StuartPegg , it does the work perfectly. First I tried the JavaScript-way, it's only 2 lines with jQuery after all. But the asynchronous loading and `ExpGroupRenderData` (and `ExpGrou...`) didn't want to play along.

Comment: @eirikb: Yeh, the 2010 list view AJAX is a mess. It gets worse when you add paging and/or web part auto-updating. Thankfully HTMLCC didn't need these fixes, although Highlighter did. :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are bound to using a ListView Webpart (OOTB web part), then you can use [Christophe's Text2HTML](http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx) script.  Elaborating on James's answer, you can also look at [Marc Anderson's DVWPCalcHTMLColumn](http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/Demos/Demo%20Pages/DVWPCalcHTMLColumn.aspx) XSLT to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a DataViewWebPart, you can force sharepoint to render the HTML as opposed to displaying the raw text by using disable-output-escaping set to yes.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. If it is possible, i want to solve this without coding. I tried the tutorial at http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/ by inserting Javascript, but it wont work.