# How can I get HTML to display properly from a calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show HTML code in column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/how-to-show-html-code-in-column)

I have a calculated column where I am generating some HTML code based on values in the list item.

How can I get HTML to display properly from a calculated column when viewing the list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been posted here (a number of times).  Here is one that answers your question: [how to show HTML code in column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/how-to-show-html-code-in-column).

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thx!