# Insert html in formula field of a calculated column in sharepoint 2007 using javascript

Tags: javascript, calculated-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show HTML code in column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/how-to-show-html-code-in-column)

Is it possible to insert html/code in the formula field of a calculated column in sharepoint 2007 using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to generate HTML as formula in Calculated Field...

Please have a look at [this post](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/)

You can [download Javascript from here](http://pathtosharepoint.com/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx), HTML Calculated Column is the one you need!

Comment: The suggested link does not answer my question, neither the possible duplicate post. What I mean is that I have some text, that can be anything, doesnt have to be html. I need a javascript to insert this text inside the Fromula field of a column in sp2007. I can read and update items in a list using javascript and CAML query but thats about as much I could do.

Comment: If its simple text you can put in <div>[your text here]</div> and this will generate simple text but if its HTML you can still have HTML inside <div>!